# Hide Javascript function on mobile or below 1200px

Tags: javascript, mobile, hide

I've just implemented this "Hide Menu on Scroll" functionality outlined on W3Schools.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_hide_scroll.asp

It's working well, however the functionality isn't quite right on mobile. Unfortunately the navbar disappears when you reach the top of page.

I'd ideally like to either fix so it remains pinned to top on mobile or just hide the javascript code all together on iPhone resolutions.

Here's the javascript...

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
} else {
document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
}
prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos; }
```

Comment: I cant reproduce the problem at this point. Could you provide the full code including HTML ? For me the navbar sits at the top as long as i am at the top of the page or am scrolling upwards. As soon as i scroll down, the navbar is hidden.

Comment: Yes. I can produce the same problem using the sample code on this page... https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_hide_scroll.asp. If you load this on mobile, the navbar disappears when you pull down on the example demonstration. The issue doesn't present itself if you scale the browser on desktop. Only on mobile (iphone both Chrome and Safari) Thanks!